# PerformancePoint analytic grid hyperlink functionality with KPI images

Tags: performancepoint, kpi

Within PerformancePoint I am trying to merge the functionality of an analytic grid with the imagery of a KPI scorecard.  The analytic grid measures contain an action that lets the user jump to a specific edit page for that measure (based on the intersection of 2 dimensions, Line of Business and Month.  That edit page is linked to a database, from which an SSIS package pulls information and processes to fill the cube.  Is it possible to add a dynamic hyperlink property to the KPI, one that is based on the intersection of the 2 dimensions, or replace the measure value in the analytic grid with images (similar to a KPI indicator)?  I was trying to do it using the API, but I haven't been able to see how to access those particular properties (the associated dimension member values).

Well, I had some screen shots that might have helped make things clearer, but don't have enough reputation to add images to a post, so Ill try and explain it in text.

I want to be able to use a hyperlink action expression such as the one below (which is functional in an analytic grid) on a scorecard KPI or baring that, use an image in place of the actual value in an analytic grid (to give it the appearance of a KPI).

/_layouts/GlobalDeliveryReporting/ProjectStatus.aspx?ProjectID=" + CSTR([Dim Project].[LOB].CurrentMember.PROPERTIES('Key1')) + "&Month=" + CSTR([Dim Status Month].[Months].CurrentMember.Member_Value))

In a nutshell:
I am trying to merge the functionality of the analytic grid action with the indicators of a scorecard Kpi.

I hope that made things a littler clearer.

Thank you

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help illustrate your question better.

Comment: Do you have to use PerformancePoint for this? It would probably be a lot easier todo using Reporting Services.

Comment: I don't believe that reporting services provides the look and feel of a PerforamncePoint report when it is displaying multidimensional data.  Reporting services reports are rendered in a standard grid format, without the row and column tree structure.

Comment: Reporting Services is fairly flexible with multi-dimensional data and can do a lot more than just displaying in a grid format.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working.

With inspiration from :
http://web.archive.org/web/20080305164525/http://blogs.msdn.com/performancepoint/archive/2007/10/05/implementing-a-hyperlink-from-a-kpi-in-a-scorecard.aspx

For those that may need to do something similar, these were the key elements:

Scorecard
 I added a hyperlink property, which causes a click event to fire every time you click on a cell.

Web Page Report
 The url for the report points to redirect.aspx.  It calls redirect.aspx with a query string parameter of EndPoint_URL which contains the dimension information of the clicked cell.

Redirect.aspx
 This page is responsible for parsing values out of EndPoint_URL.  Once the correct dimension level is achieved, it creates creates a new query string and redirects to the edit page, otherwise it just returns.  The EndPointURL ends up looking like this:

[Level1].[Level2].[Level3].&[Level4].&[Level5].&[Level6].&[Microsoft].&[Level7].&[Level8]&[69621]; [Dim Status Month].[Months].[Status Year].&[2015].&[2015-02-01T00:00:00]

In this instance, the values that need to get passed to the edit page are [69621] and [2015-02-01T00:00:00].  The redirect page parses out the EndPoint_URL, if it reaches the correct depth and finds those values, it will send the user to the edit page, otherwise it will just return.

I put the scorecard and the web page report on a dashboard.  Then connected them by passing the url and the memberuniquename of the row and column.

The downside is that it starts loading the redirect page everytime a user clicks on the scorecard, although that page is very lightweight, and once I hide the web page report web part clicking through the scorecard only causes a little blip on the screen.

Let me know if you have any questions!